# OverflowError exception not detected in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

This is my following program

```
try:
    class __Euler3__:
    n = 600851475143
    primeFactors = []

    for i in range(2,n):
        if (n%i ==0):
            primeFactors.append(i)
            n = n/i
            i = i -1 #reset i
            print primeFactors

except OverflowError as e:
       print "the error is" , e
```

but for some reason the Overflowerror mechanism is not able to catch this exception
I am using python 2.7

Comment: Your indentation is messed up and what is the purpose of `class __Euler3__`?

Comment: At what point are you expecting an exception?

Comment: Your code is not readable. I can not detect indentations.

Comment: If you fix the indentation by moving everything after `class` one level in, this will run until you run out of memory (which is a very long time, especially on a 64-bit platform), because Python integers are unlimited in size.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OverflowError is raised when you can't represent the number because it's too big.  That doesn't happen with python integers (as they seamlessly turn into `long` when they get too big, and in python3 all integers are `long` i.e. arbitrary precision.).

Quoting straight from the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.OverflowError) (with some emphasis added):

> Raised when the result of an arithmetic operation is too large to be represented. **This cannot occur for long integers** (which would rather raise MemoryError than give up) and for most operations with plain integers, which return a long integer instead. Because of the lack of standardization of floating point exception handling in C, most floating point operations also aren’t checked.

Answer (score 0):

As mgilson pointed out, no OverflowError is raised. In future, if you want to check whether the code exits silently or works, you can use try/except/else:

```
try:
    foo()
    baz()
except:
    print "error"
else:
    print "no error!"
```

Comment: Of course in this case, it will probably run for so long (especially once swap starts thrashing) that he'll never see the result, but it's still a useful tip in general. Except you really should be doing `except Exception as e: print "error:", e` rather than just `except: print "error"`. (That's the only way you're going to find out that, e.g., you're getting a different type of exception than you expected).

Answer (score 0):

According to this thread http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t701480-for-loop-range-result-has-too-many-items.html ,  range() can raise an overflow error depending on your system.  Running this code on my 32 bit system with python 2.7. I get "OverflowError('range() result has too many items',)"